# ASIHTTPRequest initialization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I need help.
I'm creating some ASIHTTPRequests, but it's crashing sometimes.

I've found, that it due to initialization.
I must use code like this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
{my code}
[request release];
```

or this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
```

Can you tell difference?

PS:
I have ten requests, which starts in one time, and one, which starts before.

Comment: Post your full code for better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a *standard* allocation, while the second implies the class method that returns an `autorelease`d object.

Assuming that you have this code inside a controller (or viewController), the `request` object presumably gets deallocated when the method ends.
So you need to keep a reference to that object inside your controller, so that it doesn't get deallocated.

So, your interface definition:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController {
    ASIHTTPRequest *request;
    // ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ASIHTTPRequest *request;

@end
```

And then the implementation

```
@implementation MyController

@sinthetyze request;

- (void) aMethodThatInstantiatesYourRequest { // using self.request means that we use the accessory method, which involves a retain call
    self.request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
    // ...
    [request release];

    // or using the autoreleased object
    self.request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
}

- (void) dealloc { // don't forget to release the request object
    [request release];
    [super release];
}
```

---

By the way, if you have more than one request, it would be better to use a network queue, so you keep a reference to the queue instead to the various single requests.

[See this gist](https://gist.github.com/150447), which uses the `ASINetworkQueue`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't crashes and it works faster than before.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference after check the source code.

The first part: need release request object manually, but this will more stable than the second type.

The second part: create the request use autorelease method. This will work correctly most time.

If your app need handle heavy request alloc and release, strongly recommend use the first way to  create asi request.